# How to use Navigation Component instead of startActivity

Tags: kotlin, navigation

In my AuthActivity, i have this code:

```
class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null) {
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).also {
                startActivity(it)
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
```

i intend to refactor the code to use **navigation component** rather than using Intent and startActivity, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with documentation- [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)